# Loop for Read and Merge multiple excel sheets in r

Tags: r, excel, merge

There are many posts about XLConnect and reading excel files in R with XLConnect like [How to read multiple excel sheets in R programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894922/how-to-read-multiple-excel-sheets-in-r-programming), including rbind function, but no one answers this question:

If i had multiple excel .xls files in a directory how can i use a loop for reading and merging
each one in order?

I have a directory so i do this:

```
 setwd("C:/Users/usuario/Desktop")
  library(rjava)
  library(XLConnect)
```

That directory has 28 excel files named like this:

```
 Bitacora_Metrocali_01_02_2014C
 Bitacora_Metrocali_02_02_2014C
         .    ...    ...
 Bitacora_Metrocali_28_02_2014C
```

So i need to merge them using the function:
      Merge(x,y,all=T)

So it can add new columns to the dataframe. The thig is, i need a dataframe that starts
merging the first wht the second,and then adding all the new sheets in order. All excel
files of interest are in sheet 1.

THX!

Comment: I can read  them, and merge too, i mean, one per one. But i have too many files. In the example i have 28, but there are more...for real. I need a loop to do that. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
# This will give you a vector of the names of files in your current directory 
# (where I've assumed the directory contains only the files you want to read)
data.files = list.files()

# Read the first file
df = readWorksheetFromFile(file=data.files[1], sheet=1)

# Loop through the remaining files and merge them to the existing data frame
for (file in data.files[-1]) {
    newFile = readWorksheetFromFile(file=file, sheet=1)
    df = merge(df, newFile, all=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: It gets some as.posixct errors but that is cuz the excel file is so complex. Thx! I did with others and works.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `lapply` and `Reduce` approach
I am using the  the read.xls from gdata package, as you mentioned **xls** files.
If it is ***xlsx*** instead, substitute `read.xls` with `readWorksheetFromFile` and load the appropriate libraries.

```
library(gdata)
data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xls") #get list of files
data.to.merge <- lapply(files, read.xls) #read in files using lapply
merged.data <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T),data.to.merge)#merge all the files
```

The merged.data will have data from all the sheets, and will also handle the case of
files with different headers.

Comment: It doesnt work to me. The gdata package doesnt work. What i have to do with perl software to achieve it?

Comment: Let me give you a positive point but help me how i can read excel files with gdata, because, i cant right now. I have windows 64-bit

Comment: Are these xlsx files or xls files?

Comment: I have some .xls files, but must are .xlsx

Comment: that's why gdata doesn't work! see my post and use `readWorksheetFromFile` instead of gdata

Comment: Give me the link to that post please

Comment: scroll up and please READ  my answer!