# R: how to group multiple sheets into one without copying the header row?

Tags: r, excel, merge, worksheet

I have hundreds of spreadsheets with thousands rows in a folder and need to group them into a single worksheet. I already managed to do this, but I ended up copying the first line that corresponds to the header and would like to delete those lines, leaving only the first line (which is supposed to be a header).

My code to merge these files in a single df is:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/R studies/base1_rawsheets") #folder with spreadsheets
library(readxl)

data.files = list.files()

df <- readxl::read_excel(data.files[1], sheet=1) #reading the first file of list

for (file in data.files[-1]){
  newFile <- readxl::read_excel(file, sheet=1)
  df <- merge(df, newFile, all=T)
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

p.s.: The code I used was adapted from that solution here [How to read multiple excel sheets in R programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894922/how-to-read-multiple-excel-sheets-in-r-programming)

Comment: Why do you want to drop the header? Maybe if you show some data we can better understand.

Comment: Each worksheet has a first row with the column names, when I group the hundreds of columns, those lines appear, and I do not need them, I need only the results that each column has. Understand?

Comment: Again please show data to better illustrate. I am very curious at this reappearing column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply drop the first observation of every captured xlsx after the first spreadsheet with [-1,].

```
df <- readxl::read_excel(data.files[1], sheet=1) #reading the first file of list

for (file in data.files[-1]){
  newFile <- readxl::read_excel(file, sheet=1)[-1,] ## Drops the first row
  df <- merge(df, newFile, all=T)
}
```

Comment: the code seems to work, it's working for about 20 minutes, I believe because the union of all the worksheets adds more than 600 thousand lines. Thank you in advance. Can you tell me how I can concatenate the F-G columns so that their contents appear in column F?

Comment: Glad it helped. Assuming that the columns are named F and G, then:
df$F <- paste(df$F, df$G, sep = ""). If you need to insert some kind of separation character, insert it within the quotes of sep = "".

Comment: Great! Great! Thank you so much, Nicolas!